# Performing a Regular Expression find-replace in nvALT

Tags: regex, macos, grep, keyboard-maestro

I'm using Keyboard Maestro on my Mac to perform a regex find-replace in an nvALT document.

The Keyboard Maestro part of it is not that complicated. It just copies selected text from nvALT, performs the find-replace, and then pastes the text.

I can capture line breaks, but can't seem to put them back in. For example, if I take the text

```
penguin
horse
robot
```

Setting the "find" string to

```
(?m)\n
```

and the "replace" string to

```
\n
```

Then I get

```
penguinnhorsenrobot
```

Obviously, the query is seeing and finding line breaks. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? What point is there to finding and replacing characters with themselves (which has no effect)?

Comment: You're absolutely right, this wouldn't change the text. I didn't really want to perform this query. I just used it as an example because it shows that regex wildcards are working as "find" strings but not as "replace" strings.

Comment: Try replacing with `\r`

Comment: Same results with \r.

Answer (score 1):

[Keyboard Maestro supports backreferences](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/documentation/6/actions.html#actions_clipboard), so you can use those to solve your problem.

You can set the 'search' string to

`(?m)(\n)`

and the 'replace' string to

`$1`

to get what you want.

Here's an example on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/hN6qP4).

Comment: Hi @Chirag64, thanks. You're right that this would solve the problem for this particular issue, but I'm looking for a more multipurpose solution. For example, a more common use case for me would be removing _double_ line breaks. I can use your solution again, but I'd have to group each line break separately in my query. Obviously that's not a very flexible solution. (Though I sincerely appreciate your help.) I'm really trying to figure out why nvALT doesn't handle this normally.